# Flash/AIR Context3D memory limits

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, opengl, air

[In the original Context3D docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display3D/Context3D.html), it says:

```
Resource            Total memory
Vertex buffers      256 MB
Index buffers       128 MB
Programs            16 MB
Textures            128 MB¹
Cube textures       256 MB
```

Is this **still true** even with the latest graphics card monsters? (I need to be able to use more than 512MB memory for textures)

If yes, is it also true in both **Flash and AIR builds?**

Comment: Bill, join the Stage3D group(https://www.facebook.com/groups/stage3d/) on Facebook and ask your question there or on the Starling forums. All the people that know about this stuff are there. I did some small web projects with Stage3D but never reached or needed to reach these limits.

Comment: it's not only true but can be less than that on some device/OS.